# How to speed up SQL when searching for previous date?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table t1 has 200k records and first few records are:

```
 -----------------------------
 |    date   |  id    | value |
 -----------------------------
 | 2/28/2019 |  abc1    | 55  |
 | 2/28/2019 |  abc2    | 44  |
 | 2/28/2019 |  abc3    | 33  |
 | 2/26/2019 |  abc1    | 22  |
 | 2/26/2019 |  abc2    | 12  |
 | 2/25/2019 |  abc1    | 11  |
 | 2/25/2019 |  abc3    | 10  |
 | 2/24/2019 |  abc1    | 10  |
 | 2/24/2019 |  abc2    | 10  |
 -----------------------------
```

I want to take abc1 from t1 and then find abc1 value for a previous date (it can be -1 day or -2 days or -3 days ... but it will be for sure in last 5 days) and display difference (value of first date - value of previous date).

I created a query that works fine for that (but slow):

```
select 
    a.date, a.id, a.value, b.value, a.value-b.value
from 
    t1 a
inner join 
    t1 b
on 
    a.id = b.id
where 
    b.date = (
        select 
            max(date) from t1
            where 
                date < a.date
                and date > dateadd(day, -5, a.date)
    )
```

That works fine but is very slow for 200K records (takes minutes).

How to speed it up? (maybe using RANK or some other more efficient approach..)

Expecting result:

```
2/28/2019 | abc1 | 33     (which is "55 - 22")
2/28/2019 | abc2 | 32     (which is "44 - 12")
2/28/2019 | abc3 | 23     (which is "33 - 10")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t1.*,
       value - lag(value) over (partition by id order by date)
from t1;
```

Whatever database you are using should be able to take advantage of an index on `(id, date, value)`.

If you want to limit this to the previous five days, then use `case` logic:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when date < dateadd(day, 5, lag(date) over (partition by id order by date))
             then value - lag(value) over (partition by id order by date)
        end)
from t1;
```